# Comparing two lines in text file & printing single line corresponding to similar dates

Tags: java, date, hashmap

I want to take line 1 and line 5 which has username and date same but in line one it contains in time,and in line 5 it contain out time 
I want to read those two lines and compare it to check whether both lines have same username and date and if so print it as single line in some other text file or in hash map

example like this : `"sangeetha-May 02, 2013 , -in-09:48:06:61 -out-08:08:19:27` (in JAVA)

This is the content of text file :

```
line 1. "sangeetha-May 02, 2013 , -in-09:48:06:61
line 2. "lohith-May 01, 2013 , -out-09:10:41:61
line 3 . "sushma-May 02, 2013 , -in-09:48:06:61
line 4. "sangeetha-May 01, 2013 , -out-08:36:38:50
line 5. "sangeetha-May 02, 2013 , -out-08:08:19:27
line 6. "sushma-May 02, 2013 , -out-07:52:13:51
line 7. "sangeetha-Jan 01, 2013 , -in-09:27:17:52-out-06:47:48:00
line 8. "madhusudhan-Jan 01, 2013 , -in-09:38:59:31-out-07:41:06:40
```

Above data is generating by using code below

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class FlatFileParser 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {    
        // The stream we're reading from
        BufferedReader in;
        BufferedWriter out1;
         BufferedWriter out2;
        // Return value of next call to next()
        String nextline;
        try 
        {
            if (args[0].equals("1"))
            {
                in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[1]));
                nextline = in.readLine();
                while(nextline != null)
                {
                    nextline = nextline.replaceAll("\\<packet","\n<packet");
                    System.out.println(nextline);
                    nextline = in.readLine();
                }
                in.close();
            }
            else
            {
                in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[1]));
                out1 = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("inValues.txt" , true));
                 out2 = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("outValues.txt"));
                nextline = in.readLine();
                HashMap<String,String> inout = new HashMap<String,String>();
                while(nextline != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (nextline.indexOf("timetracker")>0)
                        {
                            String from = "";
                            String indate = "";
                            if (nextline.indexOf("of in")>0)
                            {

                                int posfrom = nextline.indexOf("from");
                                int posnextAt = nextline.indexOf("@", posfrom);
                                int posts = nextline.indexOf("timestamp");
                                from = nextline.substring(posfrom+5,posnextAt);
                                indate = nextline.substring(posts+11, posts+23);
                                String dd = indate.split(" ")[1];
                                String key = dd+"-"+from+"-"+indate;
                                //String key = from+"-"+indate;
                                String intime = "-in-"+nextline.substring(posts+24, posts+35);
                                inout.put(key, intime);    

                            }
                            else if (nextline.indexOf("of out")>0)
                            {
                                int posfrom = nextline.indexOf("from");
                                int posnextAt = nextline.indexOf("@", posfrom);
                                int posts = nextline.indexOf("timestamp");
                                from = nextline.substring(posfrom+5,posnextAt);
                                indate = nextline.substring(posts+11, posts+23);
                                String dd = indate.split(" ")[1];
                                String key = dd+"-"+from+"-"+indate;
                                String outtime = "-out-"+nextline.substring(posts+24, posts+35);
                                if (inout.containsKey(key))
                                {
                                    String val = inout.get(key);
                                    if (!(val.indexOf("out")>0))
                                        inout.put(key, val+outtime);                    
                                }
                                else
                                    inout.put(key, outtime);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        System.err.println(nextline);
                        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
                    }
                    nextline = in.readLine();    
                }
                in.close();

                for(String key: inout.keySet())
                {
                    String val = inout.get(key);
                    out1.write(key+" , "+val+"\n");
                    System.out.println(key + val);
                }
                out1.close();
            }
        } 
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Description: These are log in and log out times of the employees,i am reading these from a log file ,but some are coming properly in single line like line 7 and line 8
                       and some are coming in different lines for same date,i want it to print in same line like example i have provided above,
                       and which ever records coming in single line both in and out time ishould retain it as it is....
                       PLZ CAN ANYBODY HELP ....!

Comment: can you share the code through which you are reading these lines?

Comment: *"PLZ CAN ANYBODY HELP ....!"*  1) Don't SHOUT at us.  2) Please use the correct spelling for words like 'you', 'your' & 'please'.  This makes it easier for people to understand and help. 3) There is no need to add the major tag in the title.

Comment: Thank you so much for your advise.. I will not repeat again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering you have a list of all lines from the file in `lstFile`.

You can do this

```
String output="",line1,line2;
for(int i=0;i<lstFile.size();i++)
{

    line1=lstFile.get(i);
    if(line1.contains("in") && line1.contains("out"))continue;
    for(int j=i+1;j<lstFile.size();j++)
    {
        line2=lstFile.get(j);

        if(line2.contains("in") && line2.contains("out"))continue;

        if(line1.contains(getNameDate(line2)) && line2.contains("out") && line1.contains("in"))
        {
              output+=line1+line2.substring(line2.lastIndexOf(","),line2.length());
              output+=System.getProperty("line.separator");
              break;
        }
    }
}
//output now contains your desired result
```

The below method would get the name and date

```
public String getNameDate(String input)
{
    return input.substring(0,input.lastIndexOf(","));
}
```

Comment: Thank you, its useful, i have doubt whether i have to put those lines in the list first.

Comment: @lk121 putting all the lines of file in list would make it more simpler to parse it

Comment: its works fine, but whatever lines are already proper with both in  and out values in one line,its not displaying those,i want to display those also.and also some resources having only intime or outtime have to display those values also and whatever is missing have to print some message there like ex : outtime or intime missing

Answer (score 0):

This is basic data parsing. In pseudo code this is how I would do it

```
Create a class that holds 4 valus, Employee, Date, InTime, OutTime
Instantiate a HashMap for all the final log lines
For each log line
    Parse the line using RegEx to find Employee, Date and in and/or out time
    Create the HashKey using Employee + Date
    See if the HashMap already contains such an object, else create one
    Populate with the in and/or out times found on the current line
Done, the HashMap now contains all parsed data.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some sample code to get you started.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ParseLogs {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BufferedReader br = null;
        try {
            String line;

            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("src/main/resources/log.txt"));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] split = line.split(" ");

                if (split.length > 2) {
                    String name = split[2].split("-")[0];
                    name = name.replace("\"", "");
                    System.out.println(name);
                }

                if (split.length > 5) {
                    String date = split[6];
                    System.out.println(date);
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (br != null) {
                    br.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The other post is correct that you need to use a regular expression and look at the patterns of the string lines so you can break them up. If possible, try to standardize the logs initially so that they fit a similar pattern and you don't need to massage the data afterward.

Here's the output the program

```
sangeetha
-in-09:48:06:61
lohith
-out-09:10:41:61
.
,
sangeetha
-out-08:36:38:50
sangeetha
-out-08:08:19:27
sushma
-out-07:52:13:51
sangeetha
-in-09:27:17:52-out-06:47:48:00
madhusudhan
-in-09:38:59:31-out-07:41:06:40
```

Notice that you still need to clean up the "name" and "date" variables for errors but hopefully that helps.